# ActiveMQ - Providing both TCP and SSL transport connections

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic, jaas

I am currently tasked to configure two ActiveMQ transport connections, one unencrypted connection using plain tcp (for testing purposes) and one encrypted connection using SSL and the JAAS plugin.

This is my `activemq.xml`

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?trace=true&amp;needClientAuth=true"/>
</transportConnectors>

<plugins>
    <jaasCertificateAuthenticationPlugin configuration="CertLogin" />
</plugins>
```

The problem is that as soon as I use the JAAS plugin the normal `tcp` connection requires me to use a SSL certificate for authentication.

```
org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:54042@61616
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to authenticate transport without SSL certificate.
```

Is there some way I can still use the `tcp` connection with using an SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you want to use the [JAAS Dual Authentication Plugin](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/ActiveMQ_Security_Guide/files/Auth-JAAS-DualAuthentPlugin.html) which is a hybrid of the certificate based version and the standard user / pass authentication model based on whether the client is using SSL or not.